# How to disable or enable os services from html soft button

Tags: javascript, html, windows, button

I have a page with html , so in my case i would to have a softkey button or slider which can function as ON & OFF ( in Single button ) main function for this button is to disable my WwanSvc whenever it is slided to OFF and to enable WwanSvc whenever i slide back to ON , so i'm looking for a help here that someone could provide good example.

Seriously i dont know anything about this since i'm a technical guy

@echo off

sc query "WwanSvc" | find "RUNNING"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO DISABLE

sc start "WwanSvc"

msg %username% DiGi Connected 
TIMEOUT 1
EXIT

:DISABLE
sc stop "WwanSvc"

msg %username% DiGi Disconnected
TIMEOUT 1
EXI

This codes i'm using for a batch file but since a batch file cant show the state so i'm looking for a change to slider which can show ON or OFF

Comment: JavaScript or HTML are not generally capable to call OS services or batch files. With IE and ActiveX you can launch a batch file, though.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client-side only language and cannot affect the system it runs on for security reasons.
Normally one would write a daemon/service in a server-side language and your Javascript app will send commands to that service which has access to affect the system.